# caption composite

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Is there any header composite availabe in swt? What my requirement is I should have one user login form available in SWT. That form should be able to show inside the view. And that form should have one caption also. First I thought to use some kind of dialogs. But I dont want to
use any dialogs. Is there any way which I can implement the same?

Comment: Could you describe your goal in more detail, or maybe create a mockup that shows what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There is an API called [Eclipse Forms](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Forms33/index.html) which was only introduced in Eclipse 3.3, so many books don't mention it. It lets you organize forms in a somewhat web-like way, with headers and sections and boxed groups and such. I think this would probably meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at `LoginDialog` in [Opal SWT Widget Library](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/LoginDialog). It provide a ready-to-use and configurable login dialog. Maybe it will be suitable for you.